# VS 2008 Run Custom Tool Menu

Tags: visual-studio-2008

What does it do?  Can someone explain what is it for please?
Thanks

[image: Run Custom Tool Context Menu Item in VS 2008]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It runs the custom tool you've defined in the `Properties` for that item, which transforms that item into a different format and places it in the solution's folder. The IDE's explanation is shown below (I've highlighted it for visibility).

[image: Properties dialog for resource file]

Comment: Thank you but I still do not understand what is it doing.  Based on the name ResXFileCodeGenerator, I assume it generates .resx files in a project?  
I am asking 'couse when I added a NewForm in MyProject in one build, then merged it to another build I was getting a MissingManifestResourceException. After adding this to my MyProj.csproj file, the error was gone:
<EmbeddedResource Include="NewForm.resx">
   <DependentUpon>NewForm.cs</DependentUpon>
   <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</EmbeddedResource>

Comment: It does **exactly** what the highlighted section says it does. If you merged a form into a different build, you forgot to also move the resource information with it. It has nothing to do with that menu option.